# unable to connect to Parse.com cloud using php script

Tags: php, parse-platform

When I try to connect my parse cloud it shows an error

`the username XYZ already taken`

I have tried this code:

```
public function setUp() {
    $this->parseUser = new parseUser;
    $this->testUser = array(
        'username' => 'XYZ',
        'password' => '*******',
        'email' => 'abc@mail.com',
        'customField' => 'customValue'
    );
}
```

my `parseconfig.php` file look like this

```
class parseConfig {
    const APPID = 'kS131sdje....';
    const MASTERKEY = 'w1d...';
    const RESTKEY = 'o16r...';
    const PARSEURL = 'https://api.parse.com/1/';
}
```

Can you help me? Is it trying to SignUp instead of Signin?

I downloaded this code from the link below and am trying to connect it to my Parse.com cloud

https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [Parse documentation for PHP for user operations](https://www.parse.com/docs/php_guide#users).

Here are two examples for signup and signin:

**Registration:**

```
$user = new ParseUser();
$user->set("username", "my name");
$user->set("password", "my pass");
$user->set("email", "email@example.com");

// other fields can be set just like with ParseObject
$user->set("phone", "415-392-0202");

try {
  $user->signUp();
  // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
} catch (ParseException $ex) {
  // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
  echo "Error: " . $ex->getCode() . " " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

**Login:**

```
try {
  $user = ParseUser::logIn("myname", "mypass");
  // Do stuff after successful login.
} catch (ParseException $error) {
  // The login failed. Check error to see why.
}
```

Comment: I did it using curl. by the way thanks [Wrrdpress Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364793/wordpress-developer) for help.

Comment: and there is no need to log in when you have MASTER KEY

Comment: It depends on your requirements. I would personally recommend against using a master key for everyday usage. I prefer to create a role that is able to do everything with the data and assign a user to this role. Then always log in with this user programmatically. This way even if this user is compromised, your master key is not. Also, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it answered your questions.